# Spotify Play Button incompatible with Opera?

Tags: opera, spotify

When I visit the Spotify Play Button demo page (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) in Opera 11.62, clicking on the Play Button gives me the (mostly-expected) popup:

```
The application "Spotify" must be launched to open the link: 
spotify:

Do you want to proceed?
```

If I click yes, the Spotify app then launches (if not already running) and gets focus, but does not play anything.  I suspect the link is getting broken by Opera somehow (notice that it has the `spotify:` protocol name but nothing after that).  The Play Button on my own site produces the same behavior.  Works fine in Firefox on the same machine.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sadly, that's the case. There's a similar issue in Opera's bug tracker.

I think your particular issue could be related to Opera's lack of support for cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). CORS support is coming is available in [Opera Next](http://www.opera.com/browser/next/), but not Opera 11.62. If it doesn't work in Next, I encourage you to [file a bug report](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/).